# helm test via Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-groovy

I'm running a basic groovy Jenkins pipeline as code for establishing a successful connection to a kubernetes cluster. Below is the code snippet which is trying to connect to a k8s cluster and listing all the releases.

```
   stage('Helm list'){
        steps{
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "kubeconfig-gke", variable:"kubeconfig")])
                {
                    helm list -a
                }
            }
    }
```

I get the following error on Jenkins console output :
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: list for class: groovy.lang.Binding
Possible solutions: class
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)

Answer (score 0):

Run it inside a shell command

```
        steps{
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "kubeconfig-gke", variable:"kubeconfig")])
                {
                 sh """
                    helm list -a
                 """
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, or just sh `helm list -a`.